# Image transform returns error

Tags: image-transforms

I'm trying to optimise page speeds for my website.
One thing I'm looking into is optimising image file sizes, but Image Transform in CraftCMS doesn't seem to work.

**Before:**

```
{% set asset = entry.providerAppBadge.one() %}
    <img src="{{ asset.getUrl()}}" alt="{{ entry.title }}" />
```

**After:**

1. Created an 'Image transform'
   [image]
2. Added Image transform name to the code as a string

```
    {% set asset = entry.providerAppBadge.one() %}
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl('appBadge50x50')}}" alt="{{ entry.title }}" />
```

3. Image does not load correctly on website. When I take a look at Google Inspect, I can see Craft CMS did load a src url (https://mywebsite.com/actions/assets/generate-transform?transformId=283), but when visiting this url directly, I get this error.
   [image]
4. FYI, When I add `width="{{ asset.getWidth('appBadge50x50') }}"`, it does load the 50px width correctly, so the Transform Image seems to be set up and recognised correctly.

Comment: It's not possible to tell what's going wrong from that error message alone – try enabling [`devMode`](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/what-dev-mode-does), which should throw up a full stack trace. Alternatively, the logs in `storage/logs` might provide a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a multi-site environment? I had a similar issue today because I did not had an absolute path set in the settings of the volume.

**Make sure you have an absolute path set for the volume**, e.g. `/home/web123/htdocs/images`. In my case, it was first set to just `images` and then to `@webroot/images` which both resulted in the error.

Comment: There goes 2 hours of my precious life… Thanks for pointing this out! Do you know why this is? I am on Craft CMS 4.3.6

Comment: I've upgraded from Craft 3 (forgot the full version) and the / was missing in the path. Didn't fix the issue but it was still missing